# Find all the ideals of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(S,+,\cdot)$ be the commutative and unitary ring given by

$$S=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\0&a \end{array}\right)\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$$

Find all the ideals.

Are they all prime ideals?

---

I found that one ideal is
$$I=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&b\\0&0 \end{array}\right)$$ and it's not a prime ideal.
How can you know that there are or are not more ideals?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that $I$ is not a prime ideal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the elements of the ideal $I$ you found are exactly the non invertible elements of the ring. It follows that if $J$ is a proper ideal then $J\subseteq I$. Also, if $J$ contains a nonzero element $\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&b\\0&0 \end{array}\right)$, then for each $c\in\mathbb{R}$ we have:

$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&c\\0&0 \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&b\\0&0 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}\frac{c}{b}&1\\0&\frac{c}{b} \end{array}\right)\in J$

And so $J=I$ in that case. So it follows that $I$ is the only nontrivial ideal.

And by the way, $I$ is a maximal ideal, so in particular it is prime.

Comment: Thank you so much and why $J\subseteq I$ ?

Comment: @B.David Because every element of a proper ideal is not invertible. If an ideal contains an invertible element then it contains $1$, and so it contains the whole ring.

Answer (score 1):

This ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb R[X]/\langle X^2\rangle$, which is essentially $\mathbb R[\varepsilon]$, where $\varepsilon$ is an element with the property that $\varepsilon^2=0$. You can show this using the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms: the homomorphism $\mathbb R[X]\longrightarrow S$ which maps $r\mapsto rE_2$ for all $r\in\mathbb R$ and $X\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ is surjective and has kernel $\langle X^2\rangle$. The fundamental theorem on homomorphisms (I think sometimes known as first isomorphism theorem) then gives us the isomorphism I claimed in the beginning.

Now you can use the correspondence theorem, which says that the ideals of $S$ are in a one-to-one correspondence with the ideals of $\mathbb R[X]$ containing $\langle X^2\rangle$. Which are pretty easy to find, since $\mathbb R[X]$ is a principal ideal domain. So you're looking for all ideals of the form $\langle p\rangle$ with $p\in\mathbb R[X]$, which contain $\langle X^2\rangle$. That's exactly the ideals generated by a divisor of $X^2$, of which there are three, up to association: $\langle 1\rangle,~\langle X\rangle$, and $\langle X^2\rangle$ itself. So there are only three ideals of $\mathbb R[X]$ containing $\langle X^2\rangle$, and thus only three ideals of $S$. Two of those are the trivial ideals, and you found the third one by yourself.