# Let $(\mathbb{R\times R,+,\otimes)}$ a commutative and unitary ring where $(a,b)\otimes(c,d)=(ac,ad+bc)$ Find all the proper ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(\mathbb{R\times R,+,\otimes)}$ a commutative and unitary ring where

$(a,b)\otimes(c,d)=(ac,ad+bc)$

Find all the proper ideals

---

I found $I=(0,b),b\in\mathbb{R}$ because

$(0,b)-(0,c)=(0,b-c)\in I$

$(e,f)\otimes (0,b)=(0,eb)\in I$

Is there another proper ideal?

Comment: Hint: what is the quotient of your ring by the ideal $I$? What ideals does the quotient have? Does $I$ contain any other ideals?

Comment: This is exactly the same ring as in your [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3958798/29335)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One important skill is being able to recognize when something seemingly unfamiliar is actually just a different guise of something familiar. In this case, I personally think the easiest way to think of this ring is as the quotient $R:=\mathbb{R}[x]\big/(x^2)$. I'll leave it to you to verify that the map from $(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},+,\otimes)$ to $R$ given by $(a,b)\mapsto \overline{a+bx}$ is an isomorphism. Now, the ideals of $R$ are in bijective correspondence with the ideals of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ containing $(x^2)$, so let $I\leqslant\mathbb{R}[x]$ be such. Since $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, we have $I=(f)$ for some polynomial $f\in\mathbb{R}[x]$. Since $x^2\in I$, $f$ must divide $x^2$, so it must be an associate of $1$, of $x$, or of $x^2$. The first and last of these correspond to the ideals $R$ and $\left\{\overline{0}\right\}$, respectively, so the only non-trivial proper ideal of $R$ is $\left(\overline{x}\right)$. Pulling this back along our isomorphism $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow R$, you can see that this corresponds exactly to the ideal that you've found.

This might seem like a roundabout solution to the problem, but I think there's a lesson to it... the ring $(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},+,\otimes)$ at first glance seems unfamiliar (and, in fact, *a priori* it's not even completely clear that it forms a ring, at least to me), but by recognizing it as a different guise of the ring $R$, we're suddenly able to apply all our intuition and knowledge about polynomials rings over a field and their quotients. You could prove the result directly if you wanted, but recognizing this isomorphism allows you to reduce it to a situation you're already familiar with. It's not a very significant simplification in this particular case, but you can imagine how much uglier the problem would initially seem if you were instead given the ring $(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},+,\otimes)$ with structure corresponding to the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]\big/(x^4)$, for instance. When you're solving a problem, it's worth taking a step back at the start and thinking about whether it's a special case of something you already know, even if it doesn't look immediately like it is.